# How to verify if a node exist and if not exist then a created during an import of .csv to neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am importing some .cvs files for my database in neo4j, but I have the data of people in three different files, so when I import the data of the person from another file that has more data, I get an error when trying to import people nodes, because I already have other nodes with those dni (constraint) in my database.

So I want to create the new node or, if it exists, retrieve its pointer to create relationships with other nodes that I keep creating while I import.

I have tried several things on the internet but I still can't find the solution

Here my code:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/D:/ACCOUNT.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ';'

MERGE (persona :Persona { dni: line.DNI, 
nombre: line.NOMBRE, 
sexo: line.SEXO, 
fechaNacimiento: line.FNACIMIENTO,
direccion: line.DIRECCION
})
```

I have tried with apoc and "with" but I still can't find the solution.
when this code finds another node with a person label and ID equal to the one entered, it gives me an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this working, you'll have to understand how `MERGE` works. The statement

```
MERGE (persona :Persona { dni: line.DNI, nombre: line.NOMBRE, sexo: line.SEXO, 
       fechaNacimiento: line.FNACIMIENTO,direccion: line.DIRECCION
})
```

will create a new `Persona` node for every distinct combination of the above properties. So, for a node with the same `dni`, but with other values of other properties, this will fail. To fix this, you should try merging the nodes on the basis of their `dni`, and then set the properties like this:

```
MERGE (persona :Persona { dni: line.DNI })
ON CREATE
SET  persona.nombre =  line.NOMBRE, 
     persona.sexo = line.SEXO, 
     persona.fechaNacimiento = line.FNACIMIENTO,
     persona.direccion = line.DIRECCION
```

The above query will ignore setting properties if a matching node is found. To set some properties when a match is found, use `ON MATCH`, like this:

```
MERGE (persona :Persona { dni: line.DNI })
ON CREATE
SET  persona.nombre =  line.NOMBRE, 
     persona.sexo = line.SEXO, 
     persona.fechaNacimiento = line.FNACIMIENTO,
     persona.direccion = line.DIRECCION
ON MATCH
// Matching logic here
```